# How to create 2 new columns from name and surename included in 1 column in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have table in Teradata SQL like below:

| NAME |
| --- |
| Johnson Simon |
| Whats Ann |
| Pitt-House Mark |
| Grahap Michael Josh |

This table in column: "NAME" contains name and surname of clients, but be aware that sometimes clients can have two-membered surname or have two names.

As a result I need:

| NAME | SURNAME | NAME_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Johnson Simon | Johnson | Simon |
| Whats Ann | Whats | Ann |
| Pitt-House Mark | Pitt-House | Mark |
| Grahap Michael Josh | Grahap | Michael Josh |

I think, that it could be done, that we can take first value from column "NAME" to the first white space and it will be value of SURNAME column, and rest values give to NAME_2, but I do not know how to write it in Teradata SQL, or maybe you have other idea how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [STRTOK](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/1XW9lcJ9SekV%7EsIzSeoYHA)

It splits tokens based on the specified list of delimiter characters and returns the nth token, where n is specified by the *tokennum* argument.

```
SELECT NAME, STRTOK(your_table.NAME, ' ', 1) as SURNAME, STRTOK(your_table.NAME, ' ', 2) as NAME_2 FROM your_table;
```

Comment: @Koler . . . Does this work for "Grahap Michael Josh"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you right. It needs an improvement for support it as NAME_2.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everything up to the first space is the surname.  And everything else is `name_2`.  One method is `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '^[^ ]+') as surname,
       regexp_replace(name, '^[^ ]+ ', '') as name_2
```

Comment: You are right Godon, but I have errro: "Function regexp_replace called with an invalid number or type of parameters, what can I do ?

Comment: @koler . . . You can be explicit about the third argument.  But I thought Teradata supported the two-argument form.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - you are correct. If the third argument is left out, matches are removed.

Comment: The Teradata-supplied REGEXP_REPLACE in TD_SYSFNLIB *does* support the 2-argument form. But there may be some legacy UDF named REGEXP_REPLACE in SYSLIB (which comes before TD_SYSFNLIB in default search order).